# nodejs fs.writeFile() creates multiple files with same contents

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to split data from an xlsx sheet into several docx files by the user name. Firstly I use `node-excel-to-json` to convert the data in excel to json format. Then I use `docxtemplater` to put the data in json format into new created docx files. The content of first file generated is right, but the content from the second file to the last file is same with the first file. It look like this:

sample.xlsx:

name phonenumber

john 123456

john 654321

jack 987654

mike 999999

input.docx (as template):{#record}{name} {phonenumber}{/record}

generated docx:

john.docx: john 123456 john 654321

jack.docx: john 123456 john 654321

mike.docx: john 123456 john 654321

here is my code

```
var excel2Json = require('node-excel-to-json');
var JSZip = require('jszip');
var Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'input.docx'), 'binary');
var zip = new JSZip(content);
var doc = new Docxtemplater();
doc.loadZip(zip);
excel2Json('../../../sample.xlsx', {
    'convert_all_sheet': false,
    'return_type': 'Object',
    'sheetName': 'phonenumber'
}, function(err, output) {
    var i = 0;
    var buf = new Array();
    var nowPerson = {
     name : output[1].author,
     data : {"record": []}
     }
    for(var singleRecord in output) {
        console.log(output[singleRecord].author);
        if((output[singleRecord].author===nowPerson.name)){
            //console.log(output[singleRecord]);
            nowPerson.data.record.push(output[singleRecord]);
        }
        else{
            console.log(nowPerson.data);
            doc.setData(nowPerson.data);
            try {
                doc.render();
            }
            catch (error) {
                var e = {
                    message: error.message,
                    name: error.name,
                    stack: error.stack,
                    properties: error.properties,
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify({error: e}));
                // The error thrown here contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a property object).
                throw error;
            }
            buf = doc.getZip()
                .generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});
            fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, nowPerson.name+'.docx'), buf);
            nowPerson.name = output[singleRecord].author;
            nowPerson.data.record = [];
            nowPerson.data.record.push(output[singleRecord]);
        }
    }
    doc.setData(nowPerson.data);
    try {
        doc.render()
    }
    catch (error) {
        var e = {
            message: error.message,
            name: error.name,
            stack: error.stack,
            properties: error.properties,
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify({error: e}));
        // The error thrown here contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a property object).
        throw error;
    }
    var buf = doc.getZip()
        .generate({type: 'nodebuffer'});
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, nowPerson.name+'.docx'), buf);

});
```

I tried both `fs.writeFile()` and `fs.writeFileSync()`, but both of them output the same result as above. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I don't know exactly how `var doc = new Docxtemplater()` works, but it seems you should better create new ones every time you want to write a new document.

Comment: i tried new every time I write a new document,but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it's just a logic bug in your loop. Seems like your `if ... else` loops over all records and manipulates that `nowPerson.data` array and writes it. (Code is hard to understand and would not survive a code review.) Get rid of `if...else`, do that `if` part first, end the loop and when you found what you are looking for, then write that file....

Comment: sry for my bad code. Ignore that code, i'm pretty sure that the json data is correct because the names of files are correct. The content is wrong.(every file content is the same as the first file). So I think the problem happened in the filestream. Anyway,thank you for your help. (you can view it in https://github.com/zyctinker/excel2word_debug/tree/master, git clone it, npm install then node index.js)

Comment: The code for the file name generation is correct, but the code that fills that data structure is not. You write every file multiple times when you hit the `else` branch...

Comment: the bug was fixed. the reason is that the var zip was manipulated, need to be read every time i want to create a new docx

Comment: congratulations!